# Intellij IDEA error: package java.rmi does not exist

Tags: java, android

I am java newbie using Intellij IDEA. Have a problem compiling Android project (java ver 1.8.0_152) which use java.rmi package. Compiler error says that it doesn't exists.
If I understand correctly, I don't need to provide this package separately because it is part of current java version?

What am I missing?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

`java.rmi` is part of the `JDK` (Java Development Kit), but unfortunately, not of the `ADK` (Android Development Kit). These are 2 different things.

You can check this post: [ADK vs JDK vs SDK difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248752/adk-vs-jdk-vs-sdk-difference) for an explanation

**EDIT**:
In the question I marked as duplicate, they suggest to use the [LiperRMI](http://lipermi.sourceforge.net/) library instead

Comment: Thnx. Obviously didn't search properly... my bad