# Why do I need to install the JDK to build a Unity app when only the Android SDK is used?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have looked at [this page](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing) but I don't understand why I have to install the Java Development Kit (JDK), when it doesn't appear to be used in the tutorial.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Why don't you just try if you need it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I'm going to try, but I just wondered what its purpose was.

Comment: any Android development requires JDK To build APK and to sign it at least

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Ok, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Because you need JDK to develop android application. Usually this was bundled with android studio so you don't need to install JDK. And also basically, Android at its core is java.

Comment: So I do have to install it? I'm slightly confused, as your answer also says that I don't need to install it.

Comment: I think you need to install it because when you are developing android using android studio, the jdk is installed in android studio folder. But now you are developing android app using unity, you still need to install the JDK.

Comment: Ah, ok. Because I'm only installing the "command line tools".

Comment: you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248752/adk-vs-jdk-vs-sdk-difference) and [this](https://boostlog.io/@mohammedalsayedomar/setup-android-sdk-and-jdk-in-unity-5adad03d47018500491f3f77)

Answer (score 3):

JDK - Java Development Kit

It is required as it consists of JVM - Java Virtual Machine. It is also needed as it converts your class to bytecode. It is the base of Application Proramming related to Android.